# Is $\frac{1}{\sqrt x}$ a converging or diverging sequence?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, divergent-series

Suppose that $\{\epsilon\}$ is a sequence of positive reals converging to 0. Check
whether the set $\{n\epsilon \}$ is bounded. 
I am looking for the answer of this question.

Comment: The title and the body do not appear to be the same question.

Comment: I think OP is trying to figure out whether their counterexample(in title) to the question in body works or not.

Comment: Statement is not true.consider $a_n=1/\log n$.

Comment: Take $\epsilon_n= \frac{1}{\sqrt n}$

Answer (score 2):

Title: yes, $\lim\limits_{x \rightarrow \infty} \frac{1}{\sqrt x}$ converges, as it is bounded below and decreasing.
Second question: No, $\{ \epsilon \}$ convergent does not imply $\{ n\epsilon \}$ converges. Consider for example, $\{\frac{1}{\sqrt n}\}$, which converges, but $\{n \frac{1}{\sqrt n}\} = \{\sqrt n\}$ does not.

Answer (score 1):

The set $\{n\varepsilon_n\}$ need not be bounded. Consider $\varepsilon_n=\frac1{\log n}.$
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac n{\log n}=\infty.$$

Answer (score 0):

Well the would mean $\epsilon_n$ must be of big O of $1/n$.theres thousands of sequences converging to zero but not of order $1/n$

Answer (score 0):

More generally, take  $\epsilon_n=\frac{1}{n^ \alpha}$ with $\alpha<1$.